# Creating some fields for a taxonomy menu with the active trail CSS classes?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary which I want to use to create some navigation on my site.

Terms:

- Weather
- Clothes
- Calendar
- Sports

I want to be able to pull these terms and put them in the  navigation of the site. However, I want to be able to rewrite the links that these terms go to, so that rather than going to the taxonomy terms default page they go to:

/topic/[insert_taxonomy_term_here]/step-2

This is because I have a view with the [name] of the taxonomy term using that term as a contextual filter.

I'm having no problem creating such a menu tree in Views, but when I grab the taxonomy terms, as a views field, they are output without the standard Drupal active trail css classes, so that I cannot style them to show them as active.

Is there a way therefore to create a taxonomy menu in a view where the fields output the Drupal active trail?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!! This is how you do it, without even thinking[image]